# require is not a function

Tags: google-maps, angular

I'm trying to add [angular 2 google maps](https://angular-maps.com/docs/getting-started.html#package-installation) to my existing angular 2 project.

I have almost succeeded. Now the only error I get is

> Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function

Apparently the offending line is line 1 in my main google maps third party library file: google-map.ts.

The line is:

```
import {Component, ElementRef, EventEmitter, OnChanges, OnInit, SimpleChange} from '@angular/core';
```

Which is weird because it doesn't say require in the line. How do I make sure require is defined as a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I had this error, it was because Angular couldn't find a component. If you check the network tab in the browser development tools of the offending page and look at the response tab for each file. Make sure the response is the actual file you expect (at present angular will not 404 if it can't find a component file)